Show that the group of upper triangle matrices in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not unimodular.
I am reading Bumps book "Automorphic Forms and Representations" and came across the claim that the left and right Haar-measures of the Borel subgroup $B$ of upper triangular matrices in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ differ and hence $B$ is not unimodular. However this fact is not proven in the book. 
Since I am currently studying the automorphic representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ could someone show me how one would go about calculating the modularity function (the function that connects left an right Haar-measures) for the subgroup of upper triangular matrices in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$?

This is standard. Denote
$$\alpha=\begin{pmatrix}x & y\\ &x^{-1} \end{pmatrix} \in B,$$
then $$d_{B,l}=\frac{1}{|x|^2}dx\wedge dy,\quad d_{B, r}=dx\wedge dy,$$
where $d_{B,l}$ (resp. $d_{B,r}$) denotes the left (resp. right) Haar measure on $B$, $dx, dy$ stands for the standard Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. This can be checked directly. For example, if
$$\alpha_0=\begin{pmatrix}x_0 & y_0\\ &x_0^{-1} \end{pmatrix} ,$$
then $$\alpha_0\alpha= \begin{pmatrix}x_0x & x_0y+y_0x^{-1}\\ &x_0^{-1} x^{-1}\end{pmatrix}. $$
Thus $$d_{B,l}(\alpha_0\alpha)=\frac{1}{|x_0x|^2}d(x_0x)\wedge d(x_0y)=d_{B,l}(\alpha).$$
This shows $d_{B,l}$ is indeed left invariant. Similarly, one can check that $d_{B,r}$ is indeed right invariant. From this, one can obtain the modulus function.

How do you evaluate $\alpha_0\alpha$ with this measure? I am not very familiar with differential forms and I wasn't able to find much online on how to use them on matrices. Do you transfer the problem to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and set $\alpha=(x,y)$ and $\alpha_0\alpha=(xy_0+y_0x^{-1})$? Then I understand how to use $d_{B,l}$ and invariance holds. In this case I am confused what happens with the bottom right entry of the matrix. Do we just ignore it?

@antonffm $B$ is topologically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\times \times \mathbb{R}$ by sending $\alpha$ to $(x,y)$.
